# Доступ к переменным из метода в классе

Tags: java, классы

Всем привет!

Допустим, есть класс А и метод внутри него method1:

```
public class A {

void method1(String row, String col){

          ret_row=row;
          ret_col=col;

}
}
```

Как можно получить доступ к переменным внутри method1 извне?

Примерно так чтобы выглядело:

```
A Acls = new A();

String data = Acls.method1("rowww", "colll").ret_row;//тут ошибка
```

Заранее прошу прощения за неграмотность. Нагуглить не удалось, возможно, потому что неверно составлял запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
public class A {
    public String ret_row, ret_col;
    A(){...};

    public A method1(String row, String col){
      ret_row=row;
      ret_col=col;
      return this;
    };
}
```